# automated docker image patching

Tags: docker

Docker and other container images have become important building blocks especially for software production pipelines. Unfortunately, several researchers (e.g. [BanyanOps](https://banyanops.com/blog/analyzing-docker-hub/)) have shown how vulnerable docker images can be, including those from the official distributors.

I was researching into the possibilities for automatic patching of such vulnerable images when discovered. According to [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stevelasker/2017/12/20/os-framework-patching-with-docker-containers-paradigm-shift/), container patching is very sensitive and error-prone. In fact, there seems to be no solution as all the papers/reports about container image vulnerabilities do not proffer patching approaches.

I will be grateful if someone has some opinions, options or even a possible solution.